Errors with run c in vscord, file is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
I have coded a scissor-paper rock game in c, it works on an online coding website. But when I paste it to vscode errors are coming out
Then I coded some easy code to test if this is a vscode issue, but it works.
I have ensured all the paths are corrected and added a new path in the Environment Variables (which I have a similar problem with Java and this method works).
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
However, the error still appears for the long c code or all the c files.
I don't get why there is an error. Please help
PS C:\Users\user_name\University\2024> ./test
Hello World!
PS C:\Users\user_name\University\2024> ./Ass1fin
./Ass1fin : The term './Ass1fin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./Ass1fin
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./Ass1fin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I want this error to be solved, and vscode to run c successfully

Are you able to view the Ass1fin.exe file after compilation, right? Which compiler have you installed in windows?

@HimanshuDutta: This is a PowerShell script. There is no compiler involved. Did you read the question?

I find the solution, I usually type the ./ in vscode to run the code (which works on the online coding website, and sometimes in vscode). I ran the code in cmd and it worked fine, so I also typed "gcc -o Ass1fin Ass1fin.c" in vscode then "./Ass1fin" which the code works!
